# MediaInfo CLI vbs multiple Audio and Text streams issue

Tags: arrays, vbscript, mediainfo

I want to output selected parameters from movie files.
I'm doing this in that way:

```
arrGeneral = Array("General;Video Format List: %Video_Format_List%","General;File name: %FileNameExtension%","General;Commercial name: %Format_Commercial%")
arrVideo = Array("Video;ID: %ID%","Video;Format: %Format/String%","Video;Format info: %Format/Info%","Video;Format profile: %Format_Profile%","Video;Bit rate: %BitRate/String%")
arrAudio = Array("Audio;ID: %ID%\n","Audio;Format: %Format%\n","Audio;Format info: %Format/Info%\n","Audio;Commercial name: %Format_Commercial%\n","Audio;Codec ID: %CodecID%\n")
arrText = Array("Text;ID: %ID%\n","Text;Format: %Format/String%\n","Text;Codec ID: %CodecID/Info%\n","Text;Title: %Title%\n","Text;Language: %Language/String%\n")

' == General section ==
 objFileToWrite.Write "General" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrGeneral)
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrGeneral(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  objFileToWrite.Write result 
 next
 objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf

' == Video section ==
objFileToWrite.Write "Video" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrVideo) 
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrVideo(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  objFileToWrite.Write result
 next
objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf

' == Audio section ==
' Here is a problem beacuse it might be more than 1 Audio stream
objFileToWrite.Write "Audio" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrAudio) 
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrAudio(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  objFileToWrite.Write result
 next
objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf
```

For General and Video streams these commands (examples):

```
MediaInfo.exe --Output="General;Video Format List: %Video_Format_List%" "Sample.mkv"
MediaInfo.exe --Output="Video;Format info: %Format/Info%" "Sample.mkv"
```

are generating single line results like for instance:

```
Video Format List: HEVC
Format info: High Efficiency Video Coding
```

so my script is properly creating output file that contain:

```
General
Video Format List: HEVC
File name: Sample.mkv
Commercial name: Matroska
Format version: Version 4
File size: 10.03 GiB
Duration: 1 h 52 min 15 s 744 ms
Overall bit rate: 12.8 Mb/s
----------
Video
ID: 1
Format: HEVC
Format info: High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile: Main 10@L4@Main
Bit rate: 8 525 kb/s
Width: 1 920 pixels
Height: 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio: 1.778
Display aspect ratio: 16:9
Frame rate mode: Constant
Frame rate: 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space: YUV
Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0
Bit depth: 10 bits
Video stream size: 6.68 GiB (67%)
----------
```

But for the Audio and Text (subtitle) there might be more than one stream and the single command:

```
MediaInfo.exe --Output="Audio;Format info: %Format/Info%\n" "Sample.mkv"
```

is generating two or more lines (depends on how many streams movie file contain) like this:

```
Format info: Digital Theater Systems
Format info: Audio Coding 3
```

As the result in output file I'm getting something like this:

```
Audio
ID: 2
ID: 3

Format: DTS
Format: AC-3

Format info: Digital Theater Systems
Format info: Audio Coding 3

Commercial name: DTS-HD Master Audio
Commercial name: Dolby Digital

Codec ID: A_DTS
Codec ID: A_AC3

Bit rate: 3 958 kb/s
Bit rate: 192 kb/s
```

but expected result is:

```
Audio #2
ID: 2
Format: DTS
Format info: Digital Theater Systems
Commercial name: DTS-HD Master Audio
Codec ID: A_DTS
Bit rate: 3 958 kb/s

Audio #3
ID: 3
Format: AC-3
Format info: Audio Coding 3
Commercial name: Dolby Digital
Codec ID: A_AC3
Bit rate: 192 kb/s
```

I think it would be necessary to insert "multiline" results of Audio and Text streams into some dynamic arrays and in the next step to go through them and insert into output file "sorted" values or the second option is to sort final output file but in both cases but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Just after posting my case I found the solution :-) Instead of new line separator "\n" I will separate results by another character, for instance pipe "|" so the result will be:          C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo_CLI\MediaInfo.exe" --Output="Text;Codec ID: %CodecID/Info%|" "C:\Temp\sample.mkv"
Codec ID: UTF-8 Plain Text|Codec ID: Picture based subtitle format used on BDs/HD-DVDs|Codec ID: UTF-8 Plain Text|Codec ID: Picture based subtitle format used on BDs/HD-DVDs|Codec ID: UTF-8 Plain Text|Codec ID: Picture based subtitle format used on BDs/HD-DVDs

Comment: If you found answer, please add it as the answer to this question instead of as a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the vbs script that can be used to collect selected attributes:

```
InVideoFile = "C:\Temp\Sample.mkv"
InVideoFile = replace(InVideoFile,chr(34),"")
inFile = Left(InVideoFile, Len(InVideoFile) -4) & "-All.txt"
outFile = Left(inFile, Len(inFile) -4) & "-MediaInfo.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if objFSO.FileExists(inFile) then
 objFSO.DeleteFile inFile
end if
' MediaInfo.exe location below in ProgramToExecute variable
' MediaInfo.exe (Interface CLI) download location: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows
ProgramToExecute = "C:\Program Files\MediaInfo\MediaInfo_CLI\MediaInfo.exe"
commandToRun = "cmd /C " & chr(34) & chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " -f " & chr(34) & InVideoFile &chr(34) & " > " &chr(34) & inFile &chr(34) & chr(34)
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run commandToRun,1,true
Set objShell = Nothing

Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile, 1)
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

Dim arrGeneral
Dim arrVideo
Dim arrAudio
Dim arrText

' Attributes that are need to be collected are taken from the result of command MediaInfo.exe --Info-Parameters
' Arrays elements are build in the following way:
' section;Text %Attribute%Delimiter
' examples:
' "General;Video Format List: %Video_Format_List%"
' "Video;Format profile: %Format_Profile%"
' "Audio;Channel(s): %Channel(s)/String%|"
' "Text;Format: %Format/String%|"
' Audio and Text sections  might contain more than one stream. Result is delimited by "|" character (can be used another) and later on is split
arrGeneral = Array("General;Video Format List: %Video_Format_List%","General;File name: %FileNameExtension%","General;Commercial name: %Format_Commercial%","General;Format version: %Format_Version%","General;File size: %FileSize/String4%","General;Duration: %Duration/String1%","General;Overall bit rate: %OverallBitRate/String%")
arrVideo = Array("Video;ID: %ID%","Video;Format: %Format/String%","Video;Format info: %Format/Info%","Video;Format profile: %Format_Profile%","Video;Bit rate: %BitRate/String%","Video;Width: %Width/String%","Video;Height: %Height/String%","Video;Display aspect ratio: %DisplayAspectRatio/String%","Video;Frame rate mode: %FrameRate_Mode/String%","Video;Frame rate: %FrameRate/String%","Video;Color space: %ColorSpace%","Video;Chroma subsampling: %ChromaSubsampling/String%","Video;Bit depth: %BitDepth/String%","Video;Video stream size: %StreamSize/String5%","Video;Colour primaries: %colour_primaries%","Video;Transfer characteristices: %transfer_characteristics%","Video;Matrix coefficients: %matrix_coefficients%")
arrAudio = Array("Audio;ID: %ID%|","Audio;Format: %Format%|","Audio;Format info: %Format/Info%|","Audio;Commercial name: %Format_Commercial%|","Audio;Codec ID: %CodecID%|","Audio;Bit rate: %BitRate/String%|","Audio;Channel(s): %Channel(s)/String%|","Audio;Channel positions: %ChannelPositions%|","Audio;Channel layout: %ChannelLayout%|","Audio;Sampling rate: %SamplingRate/String%|","Audio;Bit depth: %BitDepth/String%|","Audio;Compression mode: %Compression_Mode/String%|","Audio;Audio stream size: %StreamSize/String5%|","Audio;Title: %Title%|","Audio;Language: %Language/String%|","Audio;Default: %Default/String%|","Audio;Forced: %Forced/String%|")
arrText = Array("Text;ID: %ID%|","Text;Format: %Format/String%|","Text;Codec ID: %CodecID/Info%|","Text;Title: %Title%|","Text;Language: %Language/String%|","Text;Default: %Default/String%|","Text;Forced: %Forced/String%|")

' == General section ==
 objFileToWrite.Write "General" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrGeneral)
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrGeneral(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  resultNoCRLF = Replace(result, vbCRLF, "")
    if right(resultNoCRLF,2) <> ": " then
     objFileToWrite.Write result
    end if 
 next
 objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf

' == Video section ==
objFileToWrite.Write "Video" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrVideo) 
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrVideo(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  resultNoCRLF = Replace(result, vbCRLF, "")
    if right(resultNoCRLF,2) <> ": " then
     objFileToWrite.Write result
    end if 
 next
objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf

' == Audio section ==
' It might be more than 1 Audio stream
objFileToWrite.Write "Audio" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrAudio) 
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrAudio(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  Dim arrAudioSplit
  arrAudioSplit = Split(result,"|")
  ReDim Preserve arrA(UBound(arrAudio),UBound(arrAudioSplit)-1)
   for z = 0 to UBound(arrAudioSplit)-1
    arrA(i,z) =  arrAudioSplit(z)
   next 
 next
  for j = 0 to Ubound(arrAudioSplit) - 1
   for k = 0 to Ubound(arrAudio)
      if right(arrA(k,j),2) <> ": " then
       objFileToWrite.Write arrA(k,j) & vbCrLf
      end if
   next
  objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf
  next   

' == Text (subtitles) section ==
' It might be more than 1 Text stream
objFileToWrite.Write "Text" & vbCrLf
 for i = 0 to UBound(arrText) 
  commandToRun = chr(34) & ProgramToExecute & chr(34) & " --Output=" & chr(34) & arrText(i) & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & InVideoFile & chr(34)
  result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
  Dim arrTextSplit
  arrTextSplit = Split(result,"|")
  ReDim Preserve arrT(UBound(arrText),UBound(arrTextSplit)-1)
   for z = 0 to UBound(arrTextSplit)-1
    arrT(i,z) =  arrTextSplit(z)
   next 
 next
  for j = 0 to Ubound(arrTextSplit) - 1
   for k = 0 to Ubound(arrText)
     if right(arrT(k,j),2) <> ": " then
      objFileToWrite.Write arrT(k,j) & vbCrLf
     end if 
   next
  objFileToWrite.Write "----------" & vbCrLf
  next   

' == Menu (Chapters) section ==
' Have to be handled in different way by checking result of the command MediaInfo.exe -f inputfile
 Set objFileToRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFile, 1)
 startReadingMenu = false
 menuNextLine = 1
 do while not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
  strLineOriginal = Trim(objFileToRead.ReadLine())
  MenuNextLine = MenuNextLine + 1
  if Left(strLineOriginal,16) = "Chapters_Pos_End" then
   startReadingMenu = true
   MenuNextLine = 0
  end if 
  if startReadingMenu then
   objFileToWrite.Write "Chapters" & vbCrLf
   startReadingMenu = false
  end if  
  if MenuNextLine = 1 then
   objFileToWrite.Write strLineOriginal & vbCrLf
   MenuNextLine = 0
  end if 
 loop

' Close files
 objFileToRead.Close
 Set objFileToRead = Nothing
 objFileToWrite.Close
 Set objFileToWrite = Nothing

' Dislay result file in notepad
 DisplayInNotepad = "notepad.exe " & chr(34) & outFile &chr(34)
 commandToRun = "cmd /C " & DisplayInNotepad
 Dim objSh
 Set objSh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 objSh.Run commandToRun,0,true
 Set objSh = Nothing

' Cleanup
 if objFSO.FileExists(inFile) then
  objFSO.DeleteFile inFile
 end if
 if objFSO.FileExists(outFile) then
  objFSO.DeleteFile outFile
 end if
```

The only remaining issue is how to hide cmd window that is blinking when the line is invoked:

```
result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(commandToRun).StdOut.ReadAll
```

but this is cosmetic issue.